# my pagination for my json data is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query, react-pagination

I am using React Query to practice fetching data and displaying them in the UI. I have a JSON server that serves an array of colors with an id and a label. I want to use pagination to display only 2 colors at a time and a next button to move to the next page. I am using axios to make the API requests and passing the page number as a query parameter.

However, when I click the next button, the data is not updating and the UI shows the same colors as before. The query string for the page number is not updating the information of the next page. I don't know why this is happening and how to fix it.

Here is the code from the JSON server:

```
 "colors": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "label": "red"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "label": "blue"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "label": "green"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "label": "yellow"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "label": "black"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "label": "white"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "label": "orange"
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "label": "purple"
      }
    ]
```

Here is my code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import { useQuery } from "react-query";



const Color = () => {
const Feachcolor = (addpage) => {
    return axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/colors?_limit=2&_page=${addpage}`)
};

const [showcolor, useshowcolor] = useState(false);

const Handleshow = () => {
useshowcolor(true)
}
const [addpage, useaddpage] = useState(1)

const Addpagecontrol = () => {
useaddpage(prevPage => prevPage + 1)
};

console.log(addpage)

const {data, isLoading, isError, error} = useQuery(["colors", addpage], () => Feachcolor(addpage))
 

if (isError) {
    return <h2>{error.message}</h2>
}

if (isLoading) {
    return <div>loading...</div>
}
    return ( <>
   
    {data && data?.data.map((color) => {
      return  (<div key={color.id}>
            <h6><span>{color.id}</span> - {color.label}</h6>
        </div>)
    }) }
    <button onClick={Handleshow}>show color</button>
    {showcolor && <>
    
    <button onClick={() => useaddpage(page => page - 1)} disabled={addpage === 1}>prev</button>
    <button onClick={Addpagecontrol} disabled={addpage === 4}>next</button>  
    </>
    }
    </> 
    
    );
}
 
export default Color;
```

The expected output is that the UI should show the next 2 colors when I click the next button, and the query string should change accordingly. For example, if I start with `http://localhost:8000/colors?_limit=2&_page=1`, I should see red and blue, and when I click the next button, the URL should change to `http://localhost:8000/colors?_limit=2&_page=2` and I should see green and yellow.

The actual output is that the UI shows the same colors as before, and the query string does not change. For example, if I start with `http://localhost:8000/colors?_limit=2&_page=1`, I see red and blue, and when I click the next button, the URL stays the same and I still see red and blue.

I am using React Query version 3.34.0, axios version 0.24.0, and React version 17.0.2.

I have tried to use the `keepPreviousData` option in the useQuery hook, but it did not make any difference. I have also tried to console.log the data and the page number, but they seem to be correct.

I would appreciate any help or suggestions on how to solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you're managing the state of the page number (addpage).

The addpage state is being updated asynchronously when you call useaddpage(prevPage => prevPage + 1), but the useQuery hook is already using the old value of addpage to fetch data when it runs.

First I would rename addpage to 'currentPage'

```
const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
```

And then I would include these two functions to handle the values of the current page.

```
const handleNextPage = () => {
    setCurrentPage((prevPage) => prevPage + 1); 
};

const handlePrevPage = () => {
    setCurrentPage((prevPage) => Math.max(prevPage - 1, 1));
};
```

And then you can call these inside your on click:

```
<button onClick={handlePrevPage} disabled={currentPage === 1}> 

<button onClick={handleNextPage} disabled={data.data.length < 2}>
```

Comment: hi, I implemented your recommendations but am still experiencing the same issues, I even tried hardcoding it in my API endpoint in my browser search bar like this `http://localhost:8000/colors?_limit=2&_page=2` but only got the first and second colors,  please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the url doesn't work when you directly hard code it out like that then there isn't an issue with your react code and you need to check your JSON server implementation and review that logic. Check how the limit and page are being used.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is of your json-server Version, please downgrade your json-server version to "0.16.3", so your pagination will work correctly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Utilize the stable release of [JSON Server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server/commit/5e089b99c47b6e2f5cc292ef3f7774fde3eda8c0)

- Use the above link for more information
- I obtained this link from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server).

```
npm install -g json-server@0.17.4    # NPM
yarn global add json-server@0.17.4   # Yarn
pnpm add -g json-server@0.17.4       # PNPM
```

I faced the same problem as well, but it has been resolved by using version `0.17.4`

For a global installation, use this command:

```
yarn global add json-server@0.17.4
```